# Adding 3rd Party to Static Library - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I'm following the tutorial given [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-status-library-in-ios-tutorial#comments) to create a static library for my application. The static library relies on a 3rd party [library](https://github.com/jdg/oauthconsumer) in return. I followed method 2 and when I compiled the program it throws me the "header file not found error" as shown here [image]

I have uploaded my [static library](https://www.dropbox.com/s/90zq78om1t41ixv/Sema3ObjC.zip) and my [application project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7bwvwcq34h9x2gi/Sem3FinalCall.zip) for your reference. Any help on that?

Comment: When you use a static library, you still need the public header of that library, in order to let the compiler and linker resolving where the implementation is actually. If the method is declared anywhere, you'll get a compilation error cause i can't do the magic for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use any static library you also need header files of that static library. Follow this
1. Copy header files to your project directory (No need to add them to project).
2. Go to Build Setting -> Search paths
  There is option "Header Search Path" add path where your header files folder exist. If your header files are not under one folder then set top folder as search path and set as recursive this will recursively search for your header files.

Comment: By the way, where should I put the static library?